# The energy release by an earthquake was 1000 times greater than another earthquake. Difference between magnitudes?

Tags: calculus

> It is possible to associate the energy released during an earthquake
>   with its magnitude using the following equation: $$\log E =
>  1.44M+5.24$$
>
> Determine the difference between the magnitudes of two earthquakes,
>   knowing that the energy released by one is 1000 times greater than the
>   other's.

(Note: the $\log$ used is $\log_{10}(x)$, not $\ln$)

I did:

$$\log(E \cdot 1000) - \log(E) = \log(E)+\log(1000)-\log(E) = \log(1000) = 3$$

Then I isolated $E$:

$$E = 10^{1.44M+5.24}$$

and so

$$\log(10^{1.44M+5.24} \cdot 1000) - \log(10^{1.44M+5.24}) = 3  \Leftrightarrow \log(10^{1.44M+5.24} \cdot 10^3) - \log(10^{1.44M+5.24}) = 3 \Leftrightarrow \log(10^{1.44M+8.24}) - \log(10^{1.44M+5.24}) = 3 \Leftrightarrow (1.44M+8.24) - (1.44M+5.24) = 3 \Leftrightarrow 1.44M+8.24 - 1.44M-5.24 = 3 \Leftrightarrow 3 = 3$$

This doesn't give me the values for M. How do I solve this?

My book says the solution is 2.

Note: Considering that this problem comes from my schoolbook it is very likely that the problem is either missing information or has some error, making it impossible to solve. If you think that is the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

\begin{equation}
\log E_1=1,44M_1+5,24\\
\log E_2=\log(1000E_1)=1,44M_2+5,24
\end{equation}
 Now we can subtract these equations:

\begin{equation}
\log(1000E_1)-\log E_1=1,44M_2+5,24-(1,44M_1+5,24)\\\log(1000)+\log E_1-\log E_1=1,44M_2+5,24-(1,44M_1+5,24)\\3=1,44(M_2-M_1)\\M_2-M_1=\frac{3}{1,44}\approx2
\end{equation}